# Nodejs Maximum call stack size exceeded with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to call all the elements in a collection and it is giving Maximum call stack size exceeded error. the code is below.

```
router.get('/users',counsellorValidate, function(req, res, next) {
    users.find({},function(err,user) {
            res.render('counsellor/counsellorHome',{'userData':user,'user':req.session.user});
    });
});
```

Database Schema is given Below.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    first_name:{ 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    last_name:{ 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    email:{ 
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        unique: true  
    },
    altEmail:{ 
        type: String, 
    },
    password:{ 
        type: String, 
        required: true,
    },
    phone:{ 
        mobile:Number,
        isd:Number,
        std:Number,
        landline:Number
    },
    dob:Date,
    address:{
        line1:String,
        line2:String,
        city:String,
        state:String,
        country:String,
        pin:String
    },
    fb:String,
    twitter:String,
    linkedIn:String,
    blog:String,
    skype:String,
    maritial:String,
    gender:String,
    profile:{
        name:String,
        original_name:String
    },
    summary:String,
    resume:{
        name:String,
        original_name:String
    },
    education: [{
        school_name:String,
        city:String,
        state:String,
        board:String,
        marks:String,
        year:String,
        medium:String,
        specialization:String,
        mode :String
    }],
    scores : {
        gre:Number,
        gmat:Number,
        sat:Number,
        ielts:Number,
        toefl:Number,
        pte:Number
    },
    _email:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true,
        default:false
    },
    _approved:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true,
        default:false
    },
});
```

I have tried increasing the stack size but it gives segmentation error code dumped error.

Comment: Removed answer since it is not really relevant. However, since you are getting maximum call stack size reached I think you are calling some function in a loop that is not ending when you expect it to. This has happened to me and the problem ended up being a callback not invoked somewhere. I think you may need to post more code to put it in context.

Comment: I managed to solve this. the issue was with swig. swig was throwing this error as there was an uninitialized variable.

Comment: glad to hear you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. the issue was with swig. swig was throwing this error as there was an uninitialized variable.